# Android Studio SQLite insert image from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database handler ready, although I'm not too familiar with SQLite. I'm not exactly sure where the database is stored and where the images I wish to store in it should be.

I have 4 images. And wish to apply random image grabbing from the database and put it inside my grid layout (Which I have filled with Buttons so far).

Here is the XML Grid:

```
 <GridLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:columnCount="1"
      android:paddingTop="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">



      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
           <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button 1" />
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
           <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="start"
                 android:text="Button 2" />
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
           <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button 3" />
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
           <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="start"
                 android:text="Button 4" />
           <Space
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
      </LinearLayout>
 </GridLayout>
```

Would anyone mind explaining this to me?

Edit: My attempt at using BLOBS:

```
InsertandRetriveBlobData.java:
package com.example.brad.myapplication;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Brad on 20/07/2014.
 */


public class InsertandRetriveBlobData extends MyActivity {
    private DBhelper DbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        DbHelper = new DBhelper(this);
        Car car_One = new Car(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.photo), 1);
        DbHelper.open();
        DbHelper.insertCarDetails(car_One);
        DbHelper.close();
        car_One = null;
        DbHelper.open();
        car_One = DbHelper.retriveCarDetails();
        DbHelper.close();

        ImageView carphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        carphoto.setImageBitmap(car_One.getBitmap());

    }
}
```

DBhelper.java:

```
package com.example.brad.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by Brad on 21/07/2014.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBhelper {
    public static final String CAR_ID = "id";
    public static final String CAR_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CarDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CARS_TABLE = "Cars";

    private static final String CREATE_CARS_TABLE = "create table "
            + CARS_TABLE + " (" + CAR_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CAR_PHOTO
            + " blob not null);";

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CARS_TABLE);
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CARS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
    }

    public DBhelper(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    }

    public DBhelper open() throws SQLException {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertCarDetails(Car car) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CAR_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(car.getBitmap()));
        mDb.insert(CARS_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public Car retriveCarDetails() throws SQLException {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CARS_TABLE, new String[] { CAR_PHOTO}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CAR_PHOTO));
            cur.close();
            return new Car(Utility.getPhoto(blob));
        }
        cur.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have exactly 4 images you can put all of them into `res/drawable` directory then you can refer to them as `R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2` etc (provided the files are named `image1.png, image2.png` etc) and no need to store them in the database then. Am I missing your point?

Comment: Hi Alex, it needs to be pulled randomly from the database so I can just add more images and it applies them

Comment: If it is only you and not the user who adds images then you still can add them to the drawable folder and store only their indexes in your database (such as 1 for drawable1 etc). If your user can add more images you should go with the other answers to your question, those explaining how to deal with blobs

Comment: As Alex says, unless the images are dynamic, his solution is by far the best (better than mine, below).  There is no need to get the DB involved at all.  Pull them, randomly from the drawables folder.  Just create an array with the resource ids of the 4 images and randomly index into it.

Comment: Hey Alex, Sorry If I'm repeating what you're saying. Just trying to clarify. I can keep the images in my Drawable folders and use a Database to point to the right location where the ImageView would pull it from?

Comment: You can keep the images in Drawable folder as drawable1, drawable2 etc. Then in your DB you can have "drawable1", "drawable2" strings etc. Then after you get a string from database you can do int resId =  Context.getResources().getIdentifier(yourString, "drawable"); and then setDrawableResource(resId)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a considerable amount of code, here.

If you absolutely must put the images into the database, you will need to use a [blob](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getBlob(int)).

You will first have to save each image as a blob in a row in the db.

Once each blob is in its own row, you will have to query for the row you want.  To do that you will have to map from a random number to the primary key of one of the rows.

Next you will [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) the database to obtain a `Cursor` for the row containing the image.

Finally, you will read the blob, use a `BitmapFactory` to convert the bytes into an image and install the image in an ImageView.

... but let me hasten to add that this is all probably a bad idea!  Putting something the size of an image into a SQLite database will probably result in pretty sluggish behavior.  Better to save your images as image files, and to retrieve them from the file system.

If you are not getting the images dynamically, you can include them in your program as assets, and then this whole thing gets really simple.  Just open the asset file and use the BitmapFactory to convert it to an Image.

Comment: Hi Blake, I'm very new to all of this and have no Idea where to even start. I've been assigned this project and after everything I've read I will probably advise staying away from this method. 

As for now, I really don't know where to start with Blobs. I'm following this tutorial at the moment but it really doesn't explain what I'm doing. Nor do I understand the references it's making as it references them before it's created them: http://androidsurya.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite.html

Comment: Got it.  Please consider @Alex 's suggestion above.  The reason it is hard to find example is that is is generally a bad idea.  If resources really won't work, you are going to have to do a bit of reading.  Blobs are not all that difficult: just big byte arrays that you store in the DB.

Comment: Hey Blake, for now while I'm practicing with Blobs, I went through that tutorial and started using the Documentation you supplied above. I have edited my original post with the changes, however I am returning errors in DBhelper.java. 

http://puu.sh/ak6yv/a0cd42f31e.png

I also cannot find the library for getBitmap although, I have added this import: import android.view.TextureView;

which I found located here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html , Sorry for picking at your brain :) just trying to break each part down into something I can understand!

Answer (score 0):

Your bd is here : `data/data/package_name/databases` ,this is the internal directory for your application.

`SQLite` has the kind of `Blob` to store serialized objects, but I think like any other bank, is the most suitable for you in your images, in Android we've some options `directory`, such as: `assets`, `raw` or `directory internal` depends on your scenario.

This is a snippet of code from an application I developed a little time, as I had very few pictures, put the `assets` `folder`, and used the `UniversalImagerLoager` lib to manage the loading of images to Views

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_row, parent, false);
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
            holder.mImageViewArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.horizontal_row_id.selected);
            holder.mImageViewFolder = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.horizontal_row_id.folder);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(pontosMarcados.contains(getItem(position))){
            holder.mImageViewArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.mImageViewArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.mTextView.setText(mCategoriaWithListItens.getPontos().get(position).getName().toUpperCase());

        setFolder(holder.mImageViewFolder, mCategoriaWithListItens.getPontos().get(position).getOneFotos(0));

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setFolder(ImageView folderView, Foto foto){
        // To load image
        String Uri = "assets://images";
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri+foto.getUrl(), folderView, options);
    }
```

the `internal directory` is not accessible by the wizard, when you create the first instance of your class database, one that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, your `nome_banco.db` is created in that folder `data/data/package_name/databases/nome_banco.db`, if you install on **AVD** you can navigate to that directory by **DDMS**.

Regarding the images, for example: if you have 4 pictures "image1, image2, image3 and image4", and placed in the `Assets` folder of your project, you can save the names of the images in the db, and when show:

```
   // To load image
    String Uri = "assets://images/image1";
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri, folderView, options);
```

if you do not choose to use this lib, you can search for, load images from assets folder, and you will find quite a lot.

Comment: Hi André, I am slightly confused on the path still as I can't seem to find it in the projects path? http://puu.sh/ak13e/9c2e152786.png

I'm not sure if i'm looking in the right/wrong place. I can't see it from within Android Studio either.